# Don't my click Keeps returning a false when I use it to search

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, input

I am using the array include method to perform a deliberate search on items in my array but it keeps returning false when I click button,even though they are there.

```js
var arr = ["steve", "salewa", "Morris"]

var input = document.getElementById("mysearch")
var button = document.getElementById("but1")
but1.addEventListener("click", clicked)

function clicked() {
  var output = arr.includes("input.value")
  console.log(output)
}
```

```html
<h1>search</h1>
<input type="search" id="mysearch" name="q" placeholder="...search">
<button id="but1">check</button>
```

Comment: just remove the double quote inside the includes(). and make it something like this ---> arr.includes(input.value)

Answer (score -1):

You should be using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the array values that match a specified condition. You want to use `includes()` on each element of the array (= each name), not on the array itself, because `includes()` on an array only returns `true` or `false` when the whole name is inserted. There is a slight difference how `includes()` works on an array and how it works on a string. You want to return results where the name contains what you entered in the input field.

Also you need to get the value from the input using `input.value`. If you surround that with `"` the string `"input.value"` will be used, not what you entered.

```js
var arr = ["steve", "salewa", "Morris"]

var input = document.getElementById("mysearch")
var button = document.getElementById("but1")
but1.addEventListener("click", clicked)

function clicked() {
  var output = arr.filter(name => name.includes(input.value))
  console.log(output)
}
```

```html
<h1>search</h1>
<input type="search" id="mysearch" name="q" placeholder="...search">
<button id="but1">check</button>
```

Comment: Yes mushroomator.Nicely done,well explained.